# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not working Android

Tags: android

well, so, that´s my problem.

I need, when the user press the back bottom, to delete the stack of all activities opened:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent i = new Intent(context, CrisolMainApp.class);
    i.putExtra(CrisolMainApp.CERRAR_APP, true);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The point is that this is working with most of my phones, but yesterday I tried with a Samsung Galaxy Mini (android 2.3.3) and it is not working!! It is not deleting the stack of activities.

Anyone knows why?

EDIT: I was checking on doc, and I found out that the "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK" was added on API 11(my Samsung Galaxy Mini is working for Android 2.3.3, so, API 10).......I don´t know, but I guess that´s the problem.

Anyone knows how can I make it work the same way for API less than 11?

I was trying by adding these flags and it is not working either:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent a = new Intent(this, CrisolMainApp.class);
    a.putExtra(CrisolMainApp.CERRAR_APP, true);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
}
```

and I also tried:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent a = new Intent(this, CrisolMainApp.class);
        a.putExtra(CrisolMainApp.CERRAR_APP, true);
        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(a);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: So did you find out why isn't it working? I am facing the same problem and feel stuck forever

Comment: It was a new FLAG for Android 11. So you have to check the version programatically and act in consequence! It is not working only on <API11 devices

Answer (score 3):

A simple fix should be adding the xml attribute `android:noHistory="true"` to all of your activities, which will mean that as soon as the user leaves that Activity, it will be gone, and no back stack will be stored

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, but if I do that, every times the Activity are gonna dissapear, and that´s not what I want. I just want them to dissapear when I click on Back Button...... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You do not finish the activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, CrisolMainApp.class);
i.putExtra(CrisolMainApp.CERRAR_APP, true);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working either...... I added the finish() method after the startActivity, but still not working. The weird part is that it is working on every phones I was trying before....(Samsung Galaxy SII, Galaxy Nexus, LG Optimus Black).......it is just not working for the Samsung Galaxy Mini.

Comment: use IntentCompat instead of Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is only available in API levels >11

Comment: @Daksh Exactly how are you supposed to use IntentCompat? It's usage is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and import `import android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat;` from support library for work on API 10.

Answer (score 0):

if you add addFlags in Intent 'i' your intent ACTION_SEND will not work, but if add addFlags in response createChooser(), only create one instance of ACTION_SEND.

```
 if (i == null) i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri());
            i.setType(Constantes.IMAGE_STREAM);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, messageShare).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: you should add some text to explain how your code works, the answer isn't very clear like this.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add these flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //use this if you want to clear the stack
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // use this if you don't want to clear your home activity
```

This should clear all the activities in the stack except this one which is brought to front.
You shouldn't need to use `finish();`

Comment: @jorgeAndroid did you try without calling finish() ?