# How to use IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask()?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to implement a button that will result in my app going back to the first activity and acting as if it was (almost) restarted all over. This code

```
Intent newIntent =
        new Intent(currentActivity.getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
currentActivity.startActivity(newIntent);
```

seems to be working OK for a newer tablet that is running Android 4.1, but it doesn't work on an older device that is running Android 2.3.4.

I've found a couple of threads about this:

[Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not working Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341294/intent-flag-activity-clear-taskintent-flag-activity-new-task-not-working-androi)

[Clear all activities in a task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979171/clear-all-activities-in-a-task)

Reading the fine print leads me to believe I should be using the IntentCompat class in android-support-v4.jar, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html

Unfortunately, the documentation does not contain any examples, and I'm very unsure of how I should be using IntentCompat. The only example I've found is this: [Not start MainActivity with android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273528/not-start-mainactivity-with-android-2-3)

which leads me to believe I should be doing something like this:

```
    Intent newIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
```

But this is giving me a compiler error, saying "makeRestartActivityTask" is an undefined symbol.

I'm guessing this implies I haven't added android-support-v4.jar correctly to my build environment (IntelliJ IDEA 12 community edition), but I've tried doing that in several different ways, and it still doesn't work.

So I have two questions:

1. Does my attempted usage of IntentCompat look correct?
2. How do I get the compiler to stop saying that "makeRestartActivityTask" is an undefined symbol?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how I'm using IntentCompat

```
    Intent intentToBeNewRoot = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    ComponentName cn = intentToBeNewRoot.getComponent();

    Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);

    startActivity(mainIntent);
```

This effectively replaces my no-longer-wanted task root with MainActivity. It works in Gingerbeard and ICS. I haven't seen the "is an undefined symbol" message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me which jar file you've added to your project which contains the IntentCompat class? Are you using IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: I'm using android-support-v4.jar, version 18. I'm on eclipse, but I use gradle for my final builds and it works too.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. My mistake was that the version of android-support-v4.jar that I'd added to my project was apparently prior to version 18.

Comment: this solution work for Android 4, but is not working for Android 2.3. It just does nothing! any idea?

Comment: which support-library version are you using? I recall testing this for v4:18.0 or v4:19.0, tho I haven't tried in a long time

Comment: Not working for me in Gingerbread. I'm using support library v19.1, and a previous version didn't work as well.

Comment: Not working with PendingIntent in GingerBread. any idea please

Comment: Read the update below from @ByteHamster ... it was removed in the v27 support library

Answer (score 26):

**Update**

Google has removed the method `IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask()` in current support library versions. Instead, you can just use the plain Android API:

```
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
```

I hope this can save someone time searching for alternatives ;)

Comment: Support library 27 where the method was removed is no longer compatible with Android 2.3 **which this 5 years old question is aimed at**.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IntentCompat is deprecated which is may be deleted, but Intent class this static method

Intent mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);

So just use the above statement.